# Electric Field felt at the origin of a hemisphere

Tags: physics, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals, electromagnetism

I want to calculate the Electric Field that is felt at the origin $O$ provoked by a hemisphere of radius $R$ with uniform charge density $\sigma$.

I used spherical coordinates: $\vec{r} = -R(\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta), \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta), \cos(\phi)) = -R\vec{e_r}$. The minus sign is because the $\vec{r}$ is pointing inwards from the surface to the origin. For a small area $dq = \sigma dA = \sigma R^2 \sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta$.

Intuitively I know that only the $e_z$ component will be relevant but want to get it from the calculations so I'll consider also the other dimensions for now.

Now, for a small area segment, a small part of the Field is felt by $$d\vec{E} = \cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^2} \sigma R^2 \sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta \vec{r} = \cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma R^2 \sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta \vec{e_r}$$

Throughout the upper hemisphere:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\iint d\vec{E} &= - \cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma R^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta \vec{e_r} \\
&= -\cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma R^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta (\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\vec{e_x} + \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\vec{e_y} + \cos(\phi)\vec{e_z}) \\
&= -\cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma R^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\phi) d\theta d\phi (\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\vec{e_x} + \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\vec{e_y} + \cos(\phi)\vec{e_z}) \\
&= -\cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma R^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} (\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2(\phi) \cos(\theta) d\theta \vec{e_x} + \sin^2(\phi)\sin(\theta)\vec{e_y} d \theta + \sin(\phi)\cos(\phi) d\theta \vec{e_z}))d\phi \\
&= -\cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma R^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} 0 \vec{e_x} + 0\vec{e_y} + 2 \pi \sin(\phi)\cos(\phi) d\theta \vec{e_z}d\phi \\
&= -\cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma 2 \pi R^2 \cfrac{\sin^2(\pi / 2) - 0}{2}\vec{e_z} \\
&= -\cfrac{1}{4\epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R} \sigma \vec{e_z}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

As you can see, the Field felt at the origin gives me $$\vec{E} = -\cfrac{1}{4\epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R} \sigma \vec{e_z}$$ But it should be $$\vec{E} = -\cfrac{1}{4\epsilon_o} \sigma \vec{e_z}$$ according to the solutions.

I have been over this for hours now and can't find the mistake. The only way I can see to remove the $R$ from the denominator is to integrate over $r$ also, but it doesn't make physical sense to me since it is the surface and not a volume that is producing the Electric Field.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: shouldn't the Rs cancel here: $$d\vec{E} = \cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^2} \sigma R^2 \sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta \vec{r} = \cfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \cfrac{1}{R^3} \sigma R^2 \sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta \vec{e_r}$$

Comment: I kept them from the beginning and canceled only in the end, so you guys could easily check what could be my mistake. Because, on that step, I first consider the vector $\vec{r}$ and then the unit vector $\vec{e_r} = \frac{\vec{r}}{R}$. At least I don't see why it is wrong (but maybe has something to do with that)

Comment: This is the mistake. Expressing in spherical coordinates means you are already using normalized vectors usually written $\hat{r}$

Comment: As far as I understand it, $\vec{e_r} = (\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta), \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta), \cos(\phi))$ is the normalized vector. The vector from the surface (radius $R$) to the origin is therefore $\vec{r} = -R\vec{e_r}$. I am starting from that setup

Comment: The confusion might be the notation. Any point in $3D$ space has a representation $x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}$ that we are familiar with. There is also a representation given by $r\hat{r}+\theta\hat{\theta}+\phi\hat{phi}$. In your equation for dE, you should be using the notation $\hat{r}$

Comment: Oh, I think I'm starting to see it now! So one thing is the normalized "pointer" from the surface to the origin in spherical coordinates: that is my $\vec{e_r}$. Another thing is the very conversion from $r\theta \phi$ coordinates to the $xyz$ coordinates which I do in line 2 of my integral equation. And that should include the $R\cos(phi)$ from the transformation itself when getting the direction $\vec{e_z}$ in cartesian coordinates. Is that my mistake?

Comment: Yeah, I now understand my mistake and the reasoning behind it! Thank you!